# How to apply PanelSlideListener on com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout slidup library

Tags: java, android, listener, slideup

Hello friend i am using sothree slideup panel library i want implement listener on it How I can implement listener for detecting slid up and slide down panel
here my code
which main sothree library in XML file

`mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);`

Comment: Hello Dr Mlido please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the listener by `onPanelSlide` method. Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
}
```

You can see the full code in the demo provided on [github here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/demo/DemoActivity.java)